# rxjs debounceTime on Subject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Have a piece of code like this:

```
const hoverQueue$ = new Rx.Subject()
    .debounceTime(1000)
    .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('subject')
});

const callback = () => {
    hoverQueue$.next(true)
}
```

Which doesn't seem to work. Instead of having my events being delayed by 1s and getting only the last value emitted, they all pass through as if debounceTime doesn't exist. the same behaviour happens with delay, doesn't seem to work.
Seems to work as intended on observables. 
callback is a callback called by another library i am using.

Not sure if i have missed something or if im doing something that's not supposed to be done, cant find much about this online.

have a fiddle below with an example to demonstrate

here is a fiddle with rxjs 5.4.1 which is what im running
https://jsfiddle.net/theya222/2nhu1ka7/

and here is one with the latest version of rxjs
https://jsfiddle.net/theya222/j1uLw80d/

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hoverQueue$` is the result of executing `subscribe` on an Observable. Therefore `hoverQueue$` is a `Subcription` not an Observable and a `Subscription` does not have the method `next`.

What you have to do is this

```
const subj = new Rx.Subject();
const hoverQueue$ = subj.debounceTime(1000);

hoverQueue$.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('subject')
});

const callback = () => {
    subj.next(true)
}
```

if callback is a

> callback called by another library

take
a look at `bindCallback` method/function defined with Observable.

Comment: `debounceTime` should be a bit further down, else `hoverQueue$` is `Observable` and not `Subject`. long live typescript

Comment: @ggradnig you are right - answer edited - long live typescript